# Cumulative sum and calculation on a condition

Tags: python

So I have a dataframe with closing and opening prices, total length of 1066 rows. I want to iterate over the column 'signal' (values are available from 700th row onward, which I want to skip all the way), check if 1, then perform a calculation using the values from the corresponding columns, then compute cumulative sum in a new column. I want the code to perform the calculation only when 1 is checked.

let's say I have this dataframe:

(I don't know how to post a dataframe)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'open':[2,4,5,7,5,11], 
                   'close':[0,2,4,3,10,5], 
                   'signal':[np.nan, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1]})
```

the desired results are as if the dataframe is constructed as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'open':[2,4,5,7,5,11], 
                   'close':[0,2,4,3,10,5], 
                   'signal':[np.nan, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1], 
                   'profits':['','',-1,-1,4, 4]})
```

I have edited the code per the answer.

My code still ignore 1 in 'signal' and it just calculates the cumulative sum for the whole column, although transaction_count passes.

here is my code:

```
transaction_count = 0
for i in df['signal']:
    if i == 1:
        df['profits'] = (df['close'] - df['open']).cumsum()
        transaction_count +=1
print('transaction count:', transaction_count)
print(df['profits_rf'])
```

Comment: No need to loop. `(df.signal==1).sum()` and `(df.close - df.open).cumsum()`  will give you what you want. You can later filter out NaNs.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected behavior. Also, you might want to look into `1[i]`

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh my bad. I have edited my question

Comment: @quest I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]

In this updated case you are mixing two answers. As @quest said, you dont need to loop. But if you want to do so anyways, you could create an array and append this array to your dataframe:

```
transaction_count = 0
profits = []
cum_sum = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['signal'][i] == 1:
        cum_sum += df['close'][i] - df['open'][i]
        profits.append(cum_sum)
    else:
        profits.append(cum_sum)

df['profits'] = profits
```

[OLD]

This part seems to be the problem:

```
if i in df['signal'] == 1[i]:
```

You are already iterating over df['signal'] so you just could check if i == 1:

```
if i == 1:
```

Comment: What you suggested works, but could you please help me with another problem? I have edited my question